# Bash: How to generate lines with sequential numbers?

Tags: vim, sed

I need to create a list which will hold fqdn's of about 30 servers.

Until now, whenever I needed to create such a list, I would:

> - Open `vim`
> - Manually insert the first line
> - Yanking the first line and then pasting the line as many times as the amount of servers in the list.
> - Then, I would manually edit the host names.

For example:

```
scraper01.nj.company.com
scraper02.nj.company.com
.
.
.
```

I wanted to know if there's a way to do it (given the fact that the names are the same apart for the chronological number) automatically, maybe by using `sed` but I don't know how to do it.

Can you please assist me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with:

```
scraper01.nj.company.com
```

Press `qq` to start recording a macro in register `q`:

```
qq
```

Yank the current line:

```
yy
```

Paste it below:

```
p
```

Increment the number:

```
<C-a>
```

Stop recording:

```
q
```

Play it back 28 times:

```
28@q
```

All together:

```
qqyyp<C-a>q28@q
```

Comment: I didn't understand this part: `<C-a>`, can you please explain?

Comment: It's Ctrl+a. See `:help i_ctrl-a` and `:help key-notation`.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `vim` you could do the following:

```
:put =map(range(1,30), 'printf(''scraper%02d.nj.company.com'', v:val)')
```

In a `bash`, just use `printf` with a ranged brace expansion:

```
printf "%s\n" "scraper"{01..30}".nj.company.com"
```

Prints:

```
scraper01.nj.company.com
scraper02.nj.company.com
[...]
scraper30.nj.company.com
```

Or another solution, with a for loop:

```
for (( i=0; i<=30; i++ )) ; do printf "scraper%02d.nj.company.com\n" $i; done
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution posted by @chaos works fine, but since you tagged this with `vim`, here's another Vim way.

First, there is this very useful map for copying lines and blocks:

```viml
nnoremap <silent> <M-c>  @='"zyy"zp'<CR>
```

With it, you can write `scraper01.nj.company.com`, then go to visual mode and press <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to add 9 more copies of it (of course, you can replace `9` by any number).

Then install the [VisIncr](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=670) plugin.  With it, you can now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to mark the column of `01`, then run `:II`.  This will change the numbers to 01 ... 10.  Save, and you're done.

Both the `<M-c>` map and the `VisIncr` plugin do more than shown above.  They can be quite useful in many other situations.